# HTML Canvas animate sequence images is slow on IPAD

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have built a script which takes a sequence of images and displays them on a canvas element in a animation loop.

This works really well on my desktop, but on IPAD (3 retina) it is very slow.  Could you suggest any way to improve the performance?

```
var videoItts = 0;

function playVideo() {
    if(videoItts < 92) {
       setTimeout(function() {
           ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
           ctx.drawImage(imagesL[videoItts],0,0,1024,636);
           requestAnimationFrame(playVideo);
           videoItts ++;
       }, 1000/22)  
     }
}
requestAnimationFrame(playVideo);
```

The imagesL is an array of pre-loaded images.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not mixing setTimeout and requestAnimationFrame. You can solve it using only requestAnimationFrame:

```
var startTime = Date.now();
var fps = 22;
var lastDrawnIndex = null;
var totalFrames = 92;

function drawVideo() {
    var currTime = Date.now();
    var currFrameIndex = Math.round((currTime - startTime) / (1000/fps)) % totalFrames;

    // Since requestAnimationFrame usually fires at 60 fps, 
    // we only need to draw the image if the frame to draw 
    // actually has changed from last call to requestAnimationFrame
    if (currFrameIndex !== lastDrawnIndex) {
        ctx.drawImage(imagesL[videoItts],0,0,1024,636);
        lastDrawnIndex = currFrameIndex;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(drawVideo);
}

requestAnimationFrame(drawVideo);
```

The idea is that for every call to requestAnimationFrame we calculate, based on the elapsed time and the desired animation frame rate, which frame index to draw. If it's different from last calculated frame index we draw it. Then we schedule drawVideo to be called next animation frame by calling requestAnimationFrame(drawVideo) at the end.

The code above will loop frames 0-91 continously at 22 fps. I removed the ctx.clearRect call, it is only needed if the frames contains transparency. So you might want to add that back.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it still struggles to run on the IPAD